# $_POST superglobal in foreach loop not working

Tags: php, select, post, foreach, shopping-cart

With below code I select a quantity, then I check the Item whose quantity I have selected then I click the add button to submit the form.

```
<form name="addtocart" method="post" action="checkbox.php"> 

//foreach loop below loops through array of items fetched from the db
<?php foreach($result2 as $row) { ?>

<select name="qty">
<?php for ($i=0; $i < $row['prd_quantity'] + 1 ; $i++) { ?>
<option value = "<?php echo $i; ?>" ><?php echo $i; ?></option>;    
<?php }?>
</select>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkitem[]" id="addtocart"  value="<?php echo   $row['prd_id'] ?>" optional /></p>

<?php } ?>
enter code here
<input type="submit" value="Make Order"/>

</form>
```

After selecting, say 8 on the select element, $ordqty below still outputs 0. I am thinking its something to do with the loop and `$_POST` superglobal but

> checkitems[ ]

works. Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
$ordqty = $_POST['qty'];
//$ordqty returns 0.
```

Below is the HTML Generated for the first item whose `$row['prd_quantity'] = 8` :

```
<select name = "qty">

<option value="0">0</option>
;
<option value="1">1</option>
;
<option value="2">2</option>
;
<option value="3">3</option>
;
<option value="4">4</option>
;
<option value="5">5</option>
;
<option value="6">6</option>
;
<option value="7">7</option>
;
<option value="8">8</option>
;
</select>
```

Comment: Can you show some of the HTML that gets generated?

Comment: @CodeCaster Sorry, I dont get it, what've posted is the html? Do you mean like : <select><option value = 0 >0</option></select>

Comment: @user587244: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask), or even the whole FAQ.

Comment: @user587244 See the little **arrows** around those big numbers? These are for up and downvoting respectively. Clicking the check below accepts an answer as being correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to me like if there's more than a single row returned by your DB then there will be multiple `select` elements within your response, all named `qty`. This could explain why the form isn't posting the correct value. Have you checked that?

Try something along the lines of:

```
<select name="qty[<?php echo $row['prd_id']; ?>]">
    <?php for ($i=0; $i < $row['prd_quantity'] + 1 ; $i++) { ?>
        <option value = "<?php echo $i; ?>" ><?php echo $i; ?></option>;    
    <?php }?>
</select>
```

This will post an array of selections keyed by product IDs.

### Update

Thank you for the idea of indexing the array of selected items' quantities using product IDs worked.

And to access the elements of the qty[ ] array , I know this could be better, but I did:

```
//Array below holds the values of the quantities entered

$new_ord_qty = $_POST['qty'];

//Array below holds product ids -- in the HTML code -- prodid is the name of a hidden inputfield inside the foreach loop whose value i have set to $row['prd_id'] 

$prod_id_array = $_POST['prodid']; 

for($i=0; $i<count($checked_items_array);$i++) {

for ($i=0; $i < count($new_ord_qty); $i++) {

//Array below holds the values of the quantities entered with the prod_id_array elements as //the indices

$ord_qty = $new_ord_qty[$prod_id_array[$i]];

// Here echo will output an array of the quantities entered for the checked items
echo $ord_qty; 

}

}
```

Thanks folks.

Comment: True, there are several `select` statements returned , one for each item and they are all name qty. Probably I should do as @dale below suggests -> Hold the values in an array qty[] maybe?

Comment: No, `qty[]` by itself is not sufficient as you won't be able to tell what product the selection was aimed at. You would have to regenerate the exact query on the database just to find that out when processing the request.

Comment: Great. Thanks. It echos correctly when i do e.g `echo ordqty[12];` how do I then iterate through the array of product IDs and set values to a variable e.g `ordqty[$i] = $ord_qty;`

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue might be that you are passing the checkbox as an array `checkitems[]` but you are passing the quantity as a single `qty` might be worth changing the name of the quantity select to `qty[]`

Obviously you may also need to update your code to handle the qty being an array and match it to the checkitem value.

Answer (score 1):

The problem should be that you have multiple selects with the same name, I assume that the POST variable will show the last one, which is still set to 0. You might use an id postfix, like, qty_0, qty_1 for each dropdown list.

Could you post the HTML code the segment generates? That might helpful.

Comment: `<option value="0">0</option>
;
<option value="1">1</option>
;
<option value="2">2</option>
;
<option value="3">3</option>
;
<option value="4">4</option>
;
<option value="5">5</option>
;
<option value="6">6</option>
;
<option value="7">7</option>
;
<option value="8">8</option>`